# How to remove and replace a JPanel using a button click?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I am relatively new to Java Concurrency and this is one of my first applications of such nature.

I have been trying to add a customized JPanel named Panel of Dice which displays a randomly generated 5 faces of dice when a button "Throw" is clicked. I am using two SwingWorker Threads HumanPlayer and SystemPlayer which updates their own throws and display the results on the JFrame using the above panel.

But the expected Panel replacements do not work as expected. The following is an incomplete Throw button ActionListener implementation. Can someone point out the issue with regards to my code?

```
this.throwButton = new JButton("Throw");
        this.throwButton.addActionListener(

                new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

                        int throwNumber = throwCount % 3;

                        if(throwNumber == 1 || throwNumber == 2) {
                            int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to reroll?");

                            if(response == 0) {
                                int number = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many dice do you want throw?"));

                                if(number > 0 && number < 6) {
                                    container.remove(panel);
                                    container.remove(systemPanel);
                                    HumanPlayerCalculator human = new HumanPlayerCalculator(container, humanPlayer, game, currentScore, throwNumber, number, scoreButton);
                                    human.execute();
                                    throwCount++;
                                }
                                else {
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid number entry.", "Input Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                                }
                            }
                            else if(response == 1) {
                                if(throwNumber == 1) {
                                    humanPlayer.addScore(currentScore.getMandatoryThrow());
                                    throwCount += 2;
                                }
                                else if(throwNumber == 2) {
                                    humanPlayer.addScore(currentScore.getRerolls()[0]);
                                    throwCount += 1;
                                }
                                scoreButton.setEnabled(false);
                                newGameButton.setEnabled(true);
                            }
                            else {
                                //Do nothing
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            container.remove(panel);
                            container.remove(systemPanel);
                            currentScore = new Score();
                            HumanPlayerCalculator human = new HumanPlayerCalculator(container, humanPlayer, game, currentScore, throwNumber, 5, scoreButton);
                            human.execute();
                            scoreButton.setEnabled(true);
                            systemScore = new Score();
                            SystemPlayerCalculator systemCalculator = new SystemPlayerCalculator(container, game.getSystemPlayer(), game, systemScore, throwNumber, 5);
                            systemCalculator.execute();
                            throwCount++;
                        }

                    }

                }

            );
```

PlayerCalculator.java

```
package ac.lk.iit.coursework2;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public abstract class PlayerCalculator extends SwingWorker<Throw, Object> implements Serializable {

    private Player player;
    private Game game;
    private Container container;
    private Score score;
    private int throwCount;
    private int diceCount;

    public PlayerCalculator() {

    }

    public PlayerCalculator(Player player, Game game, Container container, Score score, int count, int diceCount) {
        this.setPlayer(player);
        this.setGame(game);
        this.setContainer(container);
        this.setScore(score);
        this.setThrowCount(count);
        this.setDiceCount(diceCount);
    }

    public Player getPlayer() {
        return player;
    }

    public void setPlayer(Player player) {
        this.player = player;
    }

    public Game getGame() {
        return game;
    }

    public void setGame(Game game) {
        this.game = game;
    }

    public Container getContainer() {
        return container;
    }

    public void setContainer(Container container) {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public Score getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(Score score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

    public int getThrowCount() {
        return throwCount;
    }

    public void setThrowCount(int throwCount) {
        this.throwCount = throwCount;
    }

    public int getDiceCount() {
        return diceCount;
    }

    public void setDiceCount(int diceCount) {
        this.diceCount = diceCount;
    }

}
```

The HumanPlayerCalculator.java class

```
package ac.lk.iit.coursework2;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class HumanPlayerCalculator extends PlayerCalculator {

    private JButton button;

    public HumanPlayerCalculator() {
        super();
    }

    public HumanPlayerCalculator(Container container, HumanPlayer player, Game game, Score score, int throwCount, int count, JButton button) {
        super(player, game, container, score, throwCount, count);
        this.setDiceCount(count);
        this.setThrowButton(button);
    }

    public JButton getThrowButton() {
        return button;
    }

    public void setThrowButton(JButton throwButton) {
        this.button = throwButton;
    }

    @Override
    protected Throw doInBackground() throws Exception {
        Throw aThrow = new Throw(this.getDiceCount());
        ArrayList<Die> faces = aThrow.getFaces();
        //Testing
        System.out.println("You:");
        for(int i = 0 ; i < faces.size() ; i++) {
            System.out.print(faces.get(i).getValue() + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Faces = " + faces.size());
        //Testing
        getContainer().add(new PanelOfDice("You", faces, "Current total = " + this.getPlayer().getScore()), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.getContainer().validate();
        this.getContainer().getComponent(0).repaint();
        return aThrow;
    }

    protected void done() {
        try {
            if(this.getThrowCount() == 0) {
                this.getScore().setMandatoryThrow(get());
            }
            else if(this.getThrowCount() == 1) {
                this.getScore().setRerolls(get(), 1);
            }
            else {
                this.getPlayer().addScore(get());
                this.getThrowButton().setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
        catch(ExecutionException executionException) {
            executionException.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error in system. Please try again.", "System Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException interruptedException) {
            interruptedException.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error in system. Please try again.", "System Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

}
```

The SystemPlayerCalculator.java

```
package ac.lk.iit.coursework2;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class SystemPlayerCalculator extends PlayerCalculator {

    public SystemPlayerCalculator(Container container, SystemPlayer player, Game game, Score score, int throwCount, int count) {
        super(player, game, container, score, throwCount, count);
    }

    @Override
    protected Throw doInBackground() throws Exception {
        Throw aThrow = new Throw(this.getDiceCount());
        ArrayList<Die> faces = aThrow.getFaces();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        //Testing
        System.out.println("Computer:");
        for(int i = 0 ; i < faces.size() ; i++) {
            System.out.print(faces.get(i).getValue() + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Faces = " + faces.size());
        //Testing
        getContainer().add(new PanelOfDice("Computer", faces, "Current total = " + this.getPlayer().getScore()), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        this.getContainer().validate();
        this.getContainer().getComponent(1).repaint();
        return aThrow;
    }

    protected void done() {
        try {
            if(this.getThrowCount() == 0) {
                this.getScore().setMandatoryThrow(get());
            }
            else if(this.getThrowCount() == 1) {
                this.getScore().setRerolls(get(), 1);
            }
            else {
                this.getPlayer().addScore(get());
            }
        }
        catch(ExecutionException executionException) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error in system. Please try again.", "System Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException interruptedException) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error in system. Please try again.", "System Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

}
```

At this juncture the SystemPlayer's throw will replace the HumanPlayer's throw display after the thread's timed waiting although they are placed in different positions based on the BorderLayout. I can't figure out why this happens.

Can someone help me in this case?

Comment: Not an answer, but I would greatly simplify all this by **not** using a SwingWorker or threads directly, but rather by using a Swing Timer and a CardLayout.

Comment: ... or even better than a CardLayout -- use a JLabel to show the dice face, and simply swap out ImageIcons to show different faces.

Comment: And finally consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We don't want to see your whole program, but rather you should condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles, has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Yep, CardLayout, if that doesn't meet your needs, consider calling revalidate and repaint on the container after you've made your updates

Comment: I called those methods but it does not work and it is compulsory to use ImageIcons as the specifications request so

Comment: No one said **not** to use ImageIcons. :)

Comment: You don't call revalidate at all, let alone on the parent container. When you add/remove a component, you need to revalidate and repaint the **parent** container

Comment: You're also violating the single thread rules of swing by updating the UI components outside of the EDT context...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the simplest choices is to use a `CardLayout`, see [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more details

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test1();
    }

    public Test1() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JPanel content;
        private CardLayout cardLayout;

        private ColorPane colorPane;
        private NumberPane numberPane;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            colorPane = new ColorPane();
            numberPane = new NumberPane();

            cardLayout = new CardLayout();

            content = new JPanel(cardLayout);
            content.add(new JPanel(), "blank");
            content.add(colorPane, "colorPane");
            content.add(numberPane, "numberPane");

            add(content);

            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            JButton rndColor = new JButton("Color");
            rndColor.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    ColorWorker colorWorker = new ColorWorker(colorPane);
                    colorWorker.execute();
                    cardLayout.show(content, "colorPane");
                }
            });
            JButton rndNumber = new JButton("Number");
            rndNumber.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    NumberWorker numberWorker = new NumberWorker(numberPane);
                    numberWorker.execute();
                    cardLayout.show(content, "numberPane");
                }
            });
            panel.add(rndColor);
            panel.add(rndNumber);

            add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }

        public class ColorPane extends JPanel {

            public ColorPane() {
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(100, 100);
            }

        }

        public class ColorWorker extends SwingWorker<Color, Color> {

            private ColorPane colorPane;

            public ColorWorker(ColorPane colorPane) {
                this.colorPane = colorPane;
            }

            @Override
            protected void process(List<Color> chunks) {
                colorPane.setBackground(chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1));
            }

            @Override
            protected Color doInBackground() throws Exception {
                int randomColors = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 100);
                Color color = null;
                for (int index = 0; index < randomColors; index++) {
                    int red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
                    int green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
                    int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
                    color = new Color(red, green, blue);
                    publish(color);
                    Thread.sleep(40);
                }
                System.out.println(color);
                return color;
            }

            @Override
            protected void done() {
                try {
                    Color color = get();
                    colorPane.setBackground(color);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

        public class NumberPane extends JPanel {

            private JLabel label;

            public NumberPane() {
                setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                label = new JLabel("...");
                add(label);
            }

            public void setNumber(int number) {
                label.setText(Integer.toString(number));
                revalidate();
                repaint();
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(100, 100);
            }

        }

        public class NumberWorker extends SwingWorker<Integer, Integer> {

            private NumberPane numberPane;

            public NumberWorker(NumberPane colorPane) {
                this.numberPane = colorPane;
            }

            @Override
            protected void process(List<Integer> chunks) {
                numberPane.setNumber(chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1));
            }

            @Override
            protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception {
                int randomNumbers = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
                int number = 0;
                for (int index = 0; index < randomNumbers; index++) {
                    number = (int) (Math.random() * 1024);
                    publish(number);
                    Thread.sleep(40);
                }
                return number;
            }

            @Override
            protected void done() {
                try {
                    int number = get();
                    numberPane.setNumber(number);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

If you can't use a `CardLayout`, then you will need to call `revalidate` AND `repaint` on the **parent** container, as you want to force the parent container to update itself.